# ul media queries broke

Tags: html, css

.gallery contains 12 li's containing images. I had formatted the .gallery using media queries to limit the number of columns in the grid to 6, 4, 3, and 2 based on browser width. After making adjustments to create a size ratio of 2:1 for all li's containing varied sized images the media queries for .gallery broke and I don't understand why: https://jsfiddle.net/0g87u1va/3/...

```
.gallery {
display: grid;
grid-gap: 0.75rem;
grid-auto-flow: dense;
padding: 40px;
list-style: none;
background: white;
width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: auto;
}

figure {
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
border: 1px solid red;
border-radius: 15px;
width:100%;
padding-top: calc(84 / 168 * 100%);
margin: auto;
box-shadow: none;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
.gallery {
grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
grid-auto-rows: minmax(max-content, 2fr);
  }
@media screen and (max-width : 505px) {
.gallery {
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
grid-auto-rows: repeat(6, 5vw);
}
}

@media (min-width : 505px) and (max-width : 800px) {
.gallery {
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
grid-auto-rows: repeat(4, 5vw);
}
}

@media (min-width : 800px) and (max-width : 1000px) {
.gallery {
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
grid-auto-rows: repeat(3, 5vw);
}
}

}
```

Comment: Proper formatting (indentation) makes this sort of thing a rare problem. Use an editor or IDE that does it for you.

Comment: @isherwood I'm new and teaching myself as I go do you have a free editor to recommend?

Comment: It's a bit off-topic to ask here, so I'll just say that a quick internet search for 'best free coding editor' returns the usual half-dozen or so, depending on your OS. Try a few and see what fits your workflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bracket at the end of the media queries should be right after the first rule set in the first query:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .gallery {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(max-content, 2fr);
  }
} /* <-- move to here */

  @media screen and (max-width : 505px) {
  .gallery {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: repeat(6, 5vw);
  }
}

@media (min-width : 505px) and (max-width : 800px) {
  .gallery {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: repeat(4, 5vw);
  }
}

@media (min-width : 800px) and (max-width : 1000px) {
  .gallery {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: repeat(3, 5vw);
  }
}
/*
} <-- Used to be here
*/
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rLks3cu1/

Comment: Thank you! .gallery now shows space between right side and browser edge?

Comment: Remove the width rule on the footer. It will automatically take up the whole page, but setting the width to 100% will force the contents of the footer to be 100%, so the padding around the content will cause the footer (including padding) to be wider than the viewport. https://jsfiddle.net/t73npud1/

Comment: OH Thank you for the clarification!!

Comment: I'm not totally sure I understand that difference but would I be able to define the number of columns using flexbox as i do using grid? https://css-tricks.com/quick-whats-the-difference-between-flexbox-and-grid/

Comment: I dont want for example a 2 rows of 5 items and a third row of 2 items. This is why I am using grid so that I can specify only rows of 6, 4, 3, and 2 columns, unless your saying I can do that in flexbox and if that would make a significant impact vs just using grid as I have it.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry for the confusion.